# Cut layer into many parts using shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, clip, splitting

I have a layer which is a map of a town, and a shapefile which shows the boundaries within that town.

I wish to cut the layer up along each of the internal boundaries so that I end up with many layers, each containing the map of one small area as defined by shapefile. I know that I can use the clip tool to cut the map to the shape of the whole shape file, but I don't know how you use the boundaries contained within the shapefile to cut the map.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10 SP5 with the ArcView License

Comment: There is a Split Tool (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000006000000) But unfortunately it is available for only ArcInfo.

Comment: Try to use hawth tools . see (http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/splitfc.php) . i don't know you can use this tool for ArcGIS (Arcview) .

Comment: The Identity tool was also useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you have updated to an ArcInfo license, I would recommend looking into a script tool called [Split Layer By Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808) from ESRI's Geoprocessing Model and Script Tool Gallery.  The general workflow for this tool is as follows:

1. Use [Union](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000s000000) or [Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000) to assign attributes from your boundaries
   shapefile to your town shapefile.
2. Run Split Layer By Attributes to export individual shapefiles based
   on an attribute field.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ArcInfo license you can use Split tool instead of Clip tool.

See [Split (Analysis)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000006000000)

> Splitting the Input Features creates a subset of multiple output
>   feature classes.
>
> The Split Field's unique values form the names of the output feature
>   classes. These are saved in the target workspace.

Comment: This is not available for ArcView; Only on ArcInfo License.

Comment: This didn't answer the questions directly (as I said I only had ArcView) lucky I have and ArcInfo Licence lying around and I upgraded

Comment: If you didn't have an ArcInfo license you could use the Split tool in QGIS to equal effect, although you may also need to do an intersect/union first as in Aaron's answer.